# Substituir dados em branco em uma lista (Python)

Tags: python, lista

Tenho uma lista que vai receber dados de inputs e faço um *for loop* para percorrer a lista encontrando strings que estão em branco para substituí-las.

Já tentei utilizar `lista.remove()` e `lista.append()`, mas o valor que substituiria a string em branco vai para o final da lista. O mais próximo que cheguei de solucionar o problema foi usando `lista.index()` como mostra o exemplo abaixo, porém ele me retorna o seguinte erro :

> Exception has occurred: TypeError
>   'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

```
lista = []

variavel_1 = lista.insert(0,input('entre com um numero:' ))
variavel_2 = lista.insert(1,input('entre com o segundo numero:' ))

for item in lista:
    if item == '':
        print(lista)
        index = lista.index('')
        insert = lista.insert("{}".format(index),input("digite o novo numero: "))
        print(lista)
```

Como faço para identificar a posição que está em branco?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para substituir o valor basta obter a posição do elemento na lista e através do índice, passar o novo valor que será obtido através do `input`. Você teve até uma boa ideia, só que acabou criando um monstro para algo simples e errando em algumas coisas.

**Entendendo o método insert e o porquê o erro foi lançado...**

Primeiro de tudo, esse `TypeError` é gerado pois você tentou utilizar o método `format` que só aceita Strings passando um valor inteiro, que no caso é o índice obtido.

O método `insert` recebe como parâmetro um valor inteiro ( posição do elemento ) e o elemento que será inserido na lista. Então o correto nesse caso seria o seguinte código:

```
lista.insert(index, input("digite o novo numero: "))
```

Um outro detalhe muito importante, é que esse método não retorna nenhum valor e também não substitui um elemento na lista. Esse método está mais para um `append` com a diferença que você pode determinar uma posição onde o elemento será colocado na lista.

**Solucionando o problema...**

Então como nós podemos substituir o valor na lista ? Basta sobrescrever o elemento na posição **x** como no exemplo abaixo:

```
# O for agora é utilizado com o range para percorrer 
# todas as posições da lista sem utilizar o método index.

for index in range(len(lista)):

    # Verifica se a string é vazia ou somente espaços.
    if lista[index] == "" or lista[index].isspace(): 

        novo_valor = input("Digite um novo número: ")
        lista[index] = novo_valor # Sobrescreve o elemento na posição "index".

print(lista)
```

**[ Extra ] Entendendo o método append e como remover valores em lista...**

Você disse na sua pergunta que tinha tentado usar o método `append` e que não sabia o porquê do novo valor ir para o final da lista. A razão disso acontecer é porque o `append` é um método para acrescentar um elemento no final da lista. Como no exemplo abaixo:

```
lista = []
lista.append("pizza")
lista.append("lasanha")
print(lista) # Saída: ["pizza", "lasanha"]
```

Você também disse que tentou utilizar `lista.delete` mas eu tenho certeza que você obteve o erro abaixo porque esse método não existe em lista.

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'delete'

Caso você queira remover algum valor, deverá utilizar o método `remove(valor)` ou `pop(indice)`. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
lista = ["pizza", "lasanha"]
lista.remove("lasanha") # Remove o elemento "lasanha".

lista = ["pizza", "lasanha"]
lista.remove(1) # Remove o elemento que está na posição 1 (no caso lasanha).
```

Comment: Cara, MUITO obrigado pela resposta clara e objetiva. Vou testar e dou o feedback.

Comment: Acredito que é mais interessante manter a condição do IF como `lista[index] == ''` senão seu código não vai aceitar que o usuário digite zero, que também é um valor _falsy_

Comment: Eu usei o lista.remove() mesmo. Eu confundi. Valeu demais cara!